# Switching between staging/production databases with an environment variable in Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure

I use Azure and slot variables to switch between staging and production databases when pushing code. The two databases will always be identical.

This is a simplified setup of how I am trying to switch between the two.

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name=“StagingDatabase” connectionString=“YYY” />
    <add name="ProductionDatabase” connectionString=“XXX” />
 </connectionStrings>
```

Constants.cs

```
public static DbContext getDatabase()
    {
        if (@Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("isDatabaseStaging"))
        {
            return new StagingDatabase();
        }
        else
        {
            return new ProductionDatabase();
        }
    }
```

The problem is in Code.cs, because I am returning DbContext, Entity Framework does not know any of the tables in the databases and won't compile citing that dbContext has no definition for Table.

Code.cs

```
public class useDatabases
{
    public static useDatabasesResponse useDatabasesImplementation(useDatabasesRequest request)
    {

        using (var db = Constants.getDatabase())
        {
            var table = db.Table.SingleOrDefault(a => a.id == request.id);
            if (table == null)
            {
                return new useDatabasesResponse
                {
                    message = “Table not found!“,
                    status = 200,
                };
            }

            // do more database stuff, etc..
        }
    } 
}
```

I should also note that both my databases have seperate .edmx files, maybe it will work fine if I can get them to use the same one?

Comment: production web.config transformation u an do .
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Is there no way to be able to change which database I want to use at runtime with an environment variable? I find that feature very useful

Comment: Yes definately... was the link helpul?

Comment: It is helpful as an alternative, but if I understand it correctly, it does not help me switch databases at runtime. It only chooses the database when the application is built

Comment: Could you help provide a code example of how web.config transformation files could take environment variables? I'm finding conflicting information on whether that is even possible

Answer (score 1):

Rather than switching on one variable, you can just define one connectionString in the web.config and then make the connectionString a slot setting in Azure:

Web.Config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Database" connectionString="YYY" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Azure settings:

[image: Azure connectionString Settings]

Comment: I feel kind of silly, I use the app settings section right above this and never noticed was a feature! So I just set the Value to the connectionString in Azure and the connectionString in webConfig won't be used at all as long as the names are the same, correct?

Comment: I have to set the connectionString to one of the databases in web.config in order to publish to Azure. It then works perfectly when I use a slot with the same exact connectionString, but won't connect correctly when I use the other slot with a different one. Not sure how to proceed

Comment: Does your application actually work with both databases? You first need to make sure that that's the case. Settings-wise, this should all just work. If the underlying database is different, that's a whole different issue

Comment: Yes it does work with both databases and both databases are currently identical in both data and tables/rows. One thing that I should have mentioned is I actually have two connection strings for each database. One for the normal connection, one for the Entity Framework connection (i.e. "Server=...." and "metadata=...") so I currently have two connection string variables defined in azure

Comment: You'd have to make sure that you add both connectionStrings in each slot. If that's the case, I can't see what else could be the problem. Did you make sure to tick the "Slot setting" checkbox?

Comment: I misunderstood my error from before, the connection works with either database as you said. It fails no matter what when I perform the swap from the original slot I published to however

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121790/discussion-between-james-and-kenneth).